# Why doesn't objdump display any entries for the .got section of the ELF binary?

Tags: linux, binary, elf

I know of the relationship between the .plt and .got sections in an ELF binary, i.e. that corresponding entries must exist in each section for each dynamically loaded function (shared library).

Indeed, a .plt entry exists for `printf`, since it is loaded from libc:

```
nlykkei@ubuntu-dev:~/Tools$ objdump -D -j .plt ~/myprog | grep printf
0000000000400530 <printf@plt>:
  400530:       ff 25 22 07 20 00       jmpq   *0x200722(%rip)        # 600c58 <printf@GLIBC_2.2.5>
```

We see that the corresponding .got entry is located at address `0x600c58`. In total, the .plt section contains 7 entries for functions in libc.

However, displaying the .got table shows only 8 bytes:

```
nlykkei@ubuntu-dev:~/Tools$ objdump -D -j .got -z ~/myprog

/home/nlykkei/myprog:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .got:

0000000000600c30 <.got>:
  600c30:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  600c32:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  600c34:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  600c36:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
```

Why doesn't `objdump` display the entire .got section with annotations (which .got entry corresponds to which .plt entry)?

Comment: (Maybe it wants to protect you from Season 8)

Answer (score 3):

The GOT entries used by the PLT are stored in the `.got.plt` section. The mapping goes from PLT to GOT, and I don’t think there’s a way to get `objdump` to perform the reverse mapping, so the best you can do is something like

```
$ objdump -d -s -j .plt -j .got.plt sysinfo

sysinfo:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .plt:
 400420 ff35e20b 2000ff25 e40b2000 0f1f4000  .5.. ..%.. ...@.
 400430 ff25e20b 20006800 000000e9 e0ffffff  .%.. .h.........
 400440 ff25da0b 20006801 000000e9 d0ffffff  .%.. .h.........
Contents of section .got.plt:
 601000 200e6000 00000000 00000000 00000000   .`.............
 601010 00000000 00000000 36044000 00000000  ........6.@.....
 601020 46044000 00000000                    F.@.....        

Disassembly of section .plt:

0000000000400420 <.plt>:
  400420:   ff 35 e2 0b 20 00       pushq  0x200be2(%rip)        # 601008 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x8>
  400426:   ff 25 e4 0b 20 00       jmpq   *0x200be4(%rip)        # 601010 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x10>
  40042c:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)

0000000000400430 <printf@plt>:
  400430:   ff 25 e2 0b 20 00       jmpq   *0x200be2(%rip)        # 601018 <printf@GLIBC_2.2.5>
  400436:   68 00 00 00 00          pushq  $0x0
  40043b:   e9 e0 ff ff ff          jmpq   400420 <.plt>

0000000000400440 <sysinfo@plt>:
  400440:   ff 25 da 0b 20 00       jmpq   *0x200bda(%rip)        # 601020 <sysinfo@GLIBC_2.2.5>
  400446:   68 01 00 00 00          pushq  $0x1
  40044b:   e9 d0 ff ff ff          jmpq   400420 <.plt>

Disassembly of section .got.plt:

0000000000601000 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_>:
  601000:   20 0e 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      .`.............
    ...
  601018:   36 04 40 00 00 00 00 00 46 04 40 00 00 00 00 00     6.@.....F.@.....
```

Comment: Thank you, @StephenKitt. Sorry, if off-topic, but why does every Linux article refer to the ".got section", if it's actually called .got.plt?

Comment: There are [some](https://systemoverlord.com/2017/03/19/got-and-plt-for-pwning.html) [articles](https://www.technovelty.org/linux/plt-and-got-the-key-to-code-sharing-and-dynamic-libraries.html) which refer to `.got.plt` ;-). There’s even [an SO question about the difference between `.got` and `.got.plt`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676472/what-is-the-difference-between-got-and-got-plt-section). I don’t know why many articles simplify by only talking about `.got`; perhaps their authors took shortcuts...

Comment: Also, shouldn't your command fail? `.got.plt` is not executable, but you use the `-d` option, which says: `-d, --disassemble        Display assembler contents of executable sections `?

Comment: No, it shouldn’t. “Display assembler contents of executable sections” asks `objdump` to show the selected sections, but only disassemble them if they’re executable. That’s why “Disassembly of section `.plt`” shows the disassembly, and “Disassembly of section `.got.plt`” only shows the contents.